# Websockets & NodeJS - Changing Browser Tabs & Sessions

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've started writing a node.js websocket solution using socket.io.

The browsers connects to the node server successfully and I get see the socket.id and all config associated with console.log(socket). I also pass a userid back with the initial connection and can see this on the server side to.

Question: I'm not sure the best way to associate a user with a connection. I can see the socket.id changes every page change and when a tab is opened up. How can I track a user and send 'a message' to all required sockets. (Could be one page or could be 3 tabs etc).

I tried to have a look at 'express-socket.io-session' but I'm unsure how to code for it and this situation.

Question: I have 'io' and 'app' variables below. Is it possible to use the 2 together? app.use(io);

Essentially I want to be able to track users (I guess by session - but unsure of how to handle different socket id's for tabs etc) and know how to reply to user or one or more sockets.

thankyou

Comment: It depends on how you authenticate your users, for example if every socket contains a token with the user's credentials, you can track the users by this token. So if you want to send a message to a specific user, search your connections to find these with the same user token.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle the situation is rely on SocketIO's rooms. Name the room after the user's unique ID. This will support multiple connections out of the box. Then, whenever you need to communicate with a particular user, simply call the message function and pass in their id, the event, and any relevant data. You don't need to worry about explicitly leaving a room, SocketIO does that for you whenever their session times out or they close their browser tab. (We do explicitly leave a room whenever they log out though obviously)

---

On the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio(server);

io.on('connect', function (socket) {
  socket.on('userConnected', socket.join);  // Client sends userId
  socket.on('userDisconnected', socket.leave);  // Cliend sends userId
});

// Export this function to be used throughout the server
function message (userId, event, data) {
  io.sockets.to(userId).emit(event, data);
}
```

On the client:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:9000');  // Server endpoint

socket.on('connect', connectUser);

socket.on('message', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});

// Call whenever a user logs in or is already authenticated
function connectUser () {
  var userId = ...  // Retrieve userId somehow
  if (!userId) return;
  socket.emit('userConnected', userId);
}

// Call whenever a user disconnects
function disconnectUser () {
  var userId = ...  // Retrieve userId somehow
  if (!userId) return;
  socket.emit('userDisconnected', userId);
}
```